# Co working Space DB architecture

Tags: database-design, mongodb

I am trying to build a platform to share the empty desks in an office with someone outside the premises to utilize the space and generate some revenue. I am thinking of three major roles:

- Member who will book a desk/seat(resources) for any period of time be it hours/days/weeks/months.
- Member who will list empty spaces in his/her office.
- Admin who will verify the listed spaces. Only verified spaces can be booked and other Admin related tasks such as managing users/resources etc.

I am trying to build this on MongoDB and want to focus on scalability.

Comment: Welcome to the site, the backend language for our purposes is totally irrelevant only that you're Mongo and what you want to do.

Comment: Welcome to DBA StackExchange. Can you clarify what your actual question is? The [DBA Help Center](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/asking) has some more information about what is on-topic for this site and how to ask good questions.

Answer (score 2):

## Mongo

Mongo is a document store. It's not a great solution to model this in a document store. You need people to list days and times desks are available. I would want to use something that could model [timestamp ranges](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/static/rangetypes.html), and with good support for transactions. I would use something like PostgreSQL.

Comment: Hi but the problem is I am not familiar with PostgreSQL in fact I am only comfortable with noSQL DBs. So please guide me to how to do this in mongodb.

Comment: @PiyushKumar You're not comfortable enough to have *anything* done in Mongo. You're cold calling and asking us to use a hammer. The problem here is that the simple is simple in Mongo, but this is not simple for Mongo. Only if you're using Mongo 4.0 which came out just **LAST WEEK** can you model this as a multidocument problem. So really to be safe with Mongo, you need to essentially make this whole thing a single document.

Answer (score 0):

As **`@Eugen Hoble`** blog documentation [here](https://dzone.com/articles/divide-and-conquer-high-scalability-with-mongodb-t) MongoDB supports horizontal scaling through **`Sharding`** , distributing data across several machines and facilitating high throughput operations with large sets of data.

An advantage of horizontal scalability is that it can provide system administrators with the ability to increase capacity on the fly, being only limited by how many machines can be connected successfully.

[Sharding](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/sharding/) allows you to add additional instances to increase capacity when required.

For further your ref [Scalability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalability)